# Can't cast context to CustomCallBack interface in FragmentAdapter of a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-cardview

I have problem when I cast the context in the FragmentAdapter of a Fragment. My app process is:
- When I click on navigation list item (Nav One) it will show the fragment with the recyclerview and cardview.
- When I click on the image of cardview list item I want get an action to show the Toast message or do something with a costom interface named (CustomCallBack).
This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView lvNavigation;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private NavigationView mNavigation;
    private LinearLayout llMianContain;
    String[] navigation = new String[]{"Nav One","Nav Two", "Nav Three","Nav Four"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        lvNavigation = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_listView);
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mNavigation= (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        llMianContain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_main_content);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        lvNavigation.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, navigation));
        lvNavigation.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                replaceFragment(i);
                lvNavigation.setItemChecked(i, true);
                hideDrawer();
            }
        });

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }
    private void replaceFragment(int position){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new OneFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TwoFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ThreeFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment= new FourFragment();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new OneFragment();
                break;
        }
        if(null!= fragment){
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.ll_main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
    private void hideDrawer(){
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    private void showDrawer(){
        mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            hideDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentOneAdapter.CustomCallBack{

    private ArrayList<ListItem> listItems;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FragmentOneAdapter adapter;

    public OneFragment() { }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
            listItems.add(new ListItem(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_48dp, "MY NAME "+ i));
        }
        adapter = new FragmentOneAdapter(listItems, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProfileClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "position "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

FragmentAdapter.java

```
public class FragmentOneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentOneAdapter.FragmentOneViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;
    final CustomCallBack customCallBack;

    public FragmentOneAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> listItems, Context context){
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
        this.customCallBack = (CustomCallBack) context;
    }
    @Override
    public FragmentOneViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_item, parent,false);
        FragmentOneViewHolder holder = new FragmentOneViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FragmentOneViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(listItems.get(position).getName());
        holder.ivProfile.setImageResource(listItems.get(position).getProfile());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
    class FragmentOneViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvName;
        ImageView ivProfile;
        LinearLayout llFooter;

        public FragmentOneViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            ivProfile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_profile);
            llFooter= (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_footer);

            ivProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    customCallBack.onProfileClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

//    MY Custom CallBack
    interface CustomCallBack{
        void onProfileClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm,

So your Fragment is implementing CustomCallBack interface

Why don't you just pass the Fragment object itself to the adapter?

for example, in the FragmentOneAdapter.java,

change:

```
public FragmentOneAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> listItems, Context context) ===> public FragmentOneAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> listItems, CustomCallBack callback)
```

then:

```
this.customCallBack = (CustomCallBack) context; ===> this.customCallBack = callback;
```

Obviously, now in OneFragment.java,

just pass 'this' as parameter as the Fragment itself is the CustomCallBack:

```
adapter = new FragmentOneAdapter(listItems, getActivity()); ===> adapter = new FragmentOneAdapter(listItems, this);
```

Comment: how can I do if I want to show the slide down animation when I click on ImageIcon?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Do you want a drag and drop animation? In that case, ItemTouchHelper.Callback will do the magic. Take a look at this example: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf Basically, you make the Callback to handle swipe or drag motion, and just apply it using attachToRecyclerView() method.